# Text in my heading should be top not bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a table it looks like [this](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2meu6ud.jpg), but the table headings should be on the same height(top)/ start at the same line.

What shall I write in my css:

```
table th{
...
}
```

Comment: Any material you post on SO should be hosted here, that image link will break and the question will be useless eventually. You should also attempt to solve this yourself before requesting this.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
table th {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```